# HyperCam2 video out of sync, ffmpeg throws video out of bounds

Tags: ffmpeg, video-recording, sync, audio-recording

I've recorded my over 2h presentation using HyperCam2 but output video is totally out of sync with audio. It looks like video is 2x faster than audio so I have 'Thanks for watching' slide in the middle of it while audio keeps playing till the end.
I've tried slowing down video with ffmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter:v "setpts=2*PTS" output.avi
```

but there is out of bound error at about 80%:

```
[msvideo1 @ 00000000044a9840]  MS Video-1 warning: stream_ptr out of bounds (7310 >= 7306)
```

so my video has not been 100% properly processed, but anyway I'm closer than before. Now audio stream ends before video at 2:03:22. 
My streams looks like this:

```
ffprobe.exe -i input.avi
ffprobe version N-71497-gedbb9b5 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libm
p3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 22.101 / 54. 22.101
  libavcodec     56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
  libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 14.100 /  5. 14.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[avi @ 0000000002d15920] non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from input.avi:
  Duration: 01:06:52.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28193 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: msvideo1 (CRAM / 0x4D415243), rgb555le, 1920x1080, 26873 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

So my question is **how can I fix my video so audio and video is synced**?